# Pandas: Efficient way of mapping subsets of multiple columns into subsets of single columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Problem

I am trying to aggregate/combine sets of multiple columns with the same name into sets of single columns. For example:

I have a dataframe that contains multiple columns with duplicate column names. For example consider this example where I have a two times a subset of multiple columns with the same column name like so:

```
    A    A     A     B     B
  0 cute tall tall  NaN   old
  1 NaN  NaN   5    NaN   NaN
  2  1   old   NaN  cute  big
```

My goal is to map each subset (AAA & BB) to its own single-column subset. The following desired output illustrates this idea:

```
      A_new          B_new
 0   "cute, tall"    "old"
 1   "5"              NaN
 2   "1, old"        "cute, big"
```

To get here, I apply the following 3 simple logics on the input dataframe:

1. Combine all non-NaN values into a string and save it to a new column.
2. When combining non-NaN values check for duplicates and only return those that are not duplicate
3. If all values are NaN return NaN

My current solution is based on for-loops, iterating through each row. However, this approach is very slow and my dataframe is quite large, hence I wonder if there is a more efficient / fast way of achieving this?

### This is my current (very slow) solution:

```
for c,j in tqdm(enumerate(columns)): # columns is a list holding all the relevant column names
    merged_values = []
    for i in (range(0,len(df))):
        values = [x for x in df[j].iloc[i] if x is not np.nan]
        values = list(set(values))
        if values == []:
            values = np.nan
        #print(values)
        elif len(values) > 1:
            values = ", ".join(values)
        else:
            values = values[0]
        merged_values.append(values)
    if c == 0:
        data = pd.DataFrame(merged_values,columns=[j+"_new"])
    else:
        data[j] = pd.DataFrame(merged_values,columns=[j+"_new])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `stack` first then `groupby` with `join` then convert back using `unstack`

```
df.stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x : ','.join(set(x))).unstack()
Out[237]: 
           A         B
0  cute,tall       old
1          5       NaN
2      1,old  big,cute
```